# Flex: "warning: unable to bind to property..." for a sortCompareFunction

Tags: apache-flex, binding

I'm used to this problem w/variables bound to attributes in Flex tags, but this problem happens in sortCompareFunctions:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn sortCompareFunction="{Sorts.Manager}">
```

...

```
[Bindable]
public final class Sorts {
    public static function Manager(obj0:Object, o0:Object):int {
```

I thought that [Bindable] tag made a difference for some other members of Sorts, but it hasn't fixed everything. What would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind properties; or properties defined as get/set methods.

You cannot bind to functions.

Now, you may be able to make a variable of type Function:

```
[Bindable]
public var sortFunction : Function = Sorts.Manager;
```

And use that as the source for your sortCompareFunction

```
<mx:DataGridColumn sortCompareFunction="{sortFunction}">
```

Comment: Well technically you _can_ bind to a function, but in this particular case it would have to be a function that returns a reference to a comparator function. ( I guess I might be creating more confusion than I'm clarifying things by saying that ;) )

Comment: That appears to have done the trick. It's a bit clunky, though. Is it really the best way?

Funny thing, declaring that class Sorts as [Bindable] worked for other mx:DataGridColumns.

Comment: For other DataGridColumns are you trying to bind functions or variables?

Comment: Functions. Except for the name, they have the exact same prototype:
 public static function ChnlLineStatus(o0:Object,o1:Object):int

Comment: Without seeing/reviewing/testing code then, I'm not sure what is going on.